# The cyclic modules and self injective ring

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

It is well-known that if R is a Noetherian ring, and  every finitely generated right R-module embeds in projective, then R is a self-injective.
My question is that could one replace "finitely generated" by "cyclic"?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: Cyclic is finitely generated (in other terminologies, one says "monogeneous"). It means "with one generator".

Comment: Yes, but the question is" If R is right Noetherian ring and every right  cyclic R-module embeds in projective, then R is a self-injective"?

Comment: Ok, I understand

Comment: Do you happen to have a reference that I could take a look at for the 'well-known' result? Thanks

Comment: www.researchgate.net/publication/225714368_Embedding_modules_in_projectives_A_report_on_a_problem